# how to access specific data in a nested json file in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a nested json file with the following structure (see image):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQltj.png)

The question is how can I access the name value in nutrient, so that the output for instance is: Protein ?

With the following code I can already access foodClass and description values, but don't know how to access the nested ones.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class HomeScreen2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen2> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen2> {
  List _items = [];

// Fetch content from the json file
  Future<void> readJson() async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/database.json');
    final data = await json.decode(response);
    setState(() {
      _items = data["SRLegacyFoods"];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text(
          'Database',
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: readJson,
              child: const Text('Load Data'),
            ),

            // Display the data loaded from database.json
            _items.isNotEmpty
                ? Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 3,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Card(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading: Text(_items[index]['foodClass']),
                            title: Text(_items[index]['description']),
                        //    subtitle: Text(_items[index]["description"]),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                : Container()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to access with:

```
_items[index]['foodNutrients']['nutrient']['name'];
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: In your json file you have `foodNutrients` as a List. So you need to read the whole list and then iterate  it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(Map<String,dynamic> foodNutrient in _items[index]['foodNutrients']){
   print(foodNutrient['nutrient']['name']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**